# make wmaker default window manager - get rid of Cinnamon

Tags: debian, window-manager, xdm, window-maker

There are a lot of questions and answers for setting the default window manager, e.g., [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/default-window-manager-session-with-xdm-24516/)  and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/376107/how-change-the-default-desktop-manager-in-debian).

I'm using Debian Jessie with XDM. I've tried editing `/etc/X11/default-display-manager` and using `update-alternatives --configure x-window-manager` to no avail.

How do I set the default window manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [archlinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/XDM) on the subject, you should be using the `.xinitrc` to set your session information. From there you'll likely be looking for the `exec` command and modifying it from `cinnamon` to `wmaker`.

Obviously not a debian resource but the [archlinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xinitrc) on `xinit` does go through configuration options in good detail, might be useful to review.

Comment: Yes. I'm a little disappointed in myself that that's what it was.